# No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 after (dual boot) Windows start and updates

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I have a dual boot (old) Asus computer which worked nicely. But when I tried to start Windows it got caught up in a boot loop for some time. When I later stopped Windows and again started Ubuntu Linux, the sound was mi[image]ssing. In Windows it works.
**I only can hear a click noise** when I start a Youtube video or directly use aplay to play a wav file.

I tried around with some tips from internet, but it did not change anything. Headphone doesn't play either.

aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

Wiedergabe: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono

$ cat /proc/asound/cards

0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf600000 irq 31

[image]

Comment: Linux 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions within the scope defined by the [help/on-topic].  General hardware/software/OS support questions are off-topic.  You may be able to find help on [su], [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines.

Comment: Sorry, saw a similar question here. 
I would like to add that I resolved it. First boot Windows again and check that sound works or use "problem solution" capability there to make it work.
Second: boot Linux again. Then put to sleep and wakeup again.

Answer (score 0):

Since sound worked before the sound card etc. is detected and not the problem.

First boot Windows again and check that sound works or use "problem solution" capability there to make it work. Second: boot Linux again. Then put to sleep and wakeup again.